# How to segregate data between user groups in Django?

Tags: data-structures, django

`django.contrib.auth` has `User` and `Group` models. I'm using the `User` model for my users, and the `Group` model to manage their broad permissions (access to admin site, access logs, etc).

I also have my own `Client` model (representing a business client corporate entity). Let's say I'm going to have many clients, and I don't want them to see each other's data.

Do I:

- Create foreign keys in the data models pointing to the `Client`, extend the `User` model with a foreign key to the `Client` and check that the `User` and the data models both point to the same `Client` before allowing data access?
- Extend the data models to point to the `Group`, and check that the `User` and data models point to the same `Group` beforing allowing data access?
- 1-to-1 relationship between `User` and `UserProfile`, and then foreign key from `UserProfile` to `Client`?
- Something else?

My preference is to avoid extending anything in `django.contrib.auth` because it's probably going to break upgrades and middleware.